# Randomize Array then retrieve in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I'm trying to output the values of an array randomly, so there is no order to the way they are displayed. It works, not as expected.

They still display in the same order they are listed in the array, so I must be missing something..

```
    $itemArray = array("item1.php", "item2.php", "item3.php");
        shuffle($itemArray); 

        foreach ($itemArray as $item) {
                    shuffle($itemArray); 

                    include($itemArray[0]);

                }
```

Should I be using rand_array instead?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `foreach` the variable `$item` contains the current item, so it would look like:

```
foreach($itemArray as $item) {
    include($item);
}
```

Not sure what the reasoning is for including files in a random order, though...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for shuffle it again inside your foreach.

```
$itemArray = array("item1.php", "item2.php", "item3.php");
shuffle($itemArray); 

foreach ($itemArray as $item) {
     include($item);
}
```

Read the documentation for the correct use of foreach:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Simply this will suffice:

```
$itemArray = array("item1.php", "item2.php", "item3.php");
shuffle($itemArray); 

foreach ($itemArray as $item) {
    include($item);
}
```

1. `shuffle()` randomizes the array in-place, calling it multiple times is unnecessary and can cause items to be repeated or omitted.
2. You are looping through the elements in `$itemArray`, but repeatedly including `$itemArray[0]` for each iteration rather than the current item.